# Something in Common, but Unequal

Tags: fallacies

It is true that if two things---call them A and B---have something in common, it doesn't necessarily mean that A and B have everything in common. This is obvious. However, many people today reason in such a way that they violate this truth. (Example: Muslims believe there is only one god. Jews believe there is only one god. Therefore, Muslims and Jews worship the same god.) *Is there a specific name given to such a fallacy?*

Comment: I don't think most people make that argument in that way. It is better understood as an argument about direct reference: Muslims worship a God which they believe is the same God that Abraham worshipped. So do Christians and Jews. Therefore, they worship the same God.
I think the best way to understand if this is going wrong here is to consider a de re/de dicto distinction. Is there a thing such that it is God and it is worshipped by all three religions? If you deny that and don't think there exist three God's then you must explain the reference faillure of whoever doesn't worship the one God.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different fallacies you could be talking about, at different levels of intellectual subtlety:

1) Affirming the Consequent -- "I have ears.  Dogs have ears.  I am a dog." involves following an arrow of implication backward.  (D -> E; I -> E does not imply I -> E -> D, because E !-> D.)  You can see this as the form of the example, but most people making the argument simply are not that silly.

2) Overextended analogy -- When two things can be described in the same way, there is only an analogy between them, and not all aspects of that analogy will apply.  The Jewish God and the Muslim God have various aspects in common, singleness, omnipotence, etc.  They are therefore likely to have other aspects in common, e.g. ineffability, immanence, eternality, etc.  But not others, e.g. playing parts in the same stories, being worshiped by the same set of people.  Again, most people making this argument are more sophisticated than that.

3) Reification of Fictions or Potentials -- The fallacy of treating the elements of stories or theories as material realities.  If God (like Earth) were a material reality, then there would be no fallacy.  If we both believe there is only one Earth, surely we believe in the same one.  But God is not a material object like Earth.  If we both like blue, there is not necessarily a color upon which we can agree.  Blue is an abstraction, which is merely potential.  (As is any description of God if you think for two seconds.)  This seems like the fallacy you are after.

The problem is that those who make the argument do not see their God as fictional, but as real, and they don't like the idea that their image of him is necessarily incomplete.

Comment: After looking at this a bit more, I may have in mind the fallacy of the undistributed middle (I can't believe I didn't think of this one earlier). But your answer is a good one. I appreciate it. I want to look into some of the things you mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

Is it a fallacy?

If Muslims believe there is only one god, and under the assumption that this belief is correct, there would be exactly one god. Christians couldn't possibly believe in a different really existing god, because there isn't any other. So assuming the Muslim belief is correct, Muslims and Christians believe in the same god.

Of course Muslims and Christians have different believes how this god wants them to behave. And of course Muslims and Christians could be both wrong about there being exactly one god (there might be none or many).

If you picked a better example, it would probably just be a non sequitur. Same as "You drive a car, and I drive a car, therefore we drive the same car". Just a non-sequitur again, just more obvious. (If you claimed that you drive the only car in existence, and I claimed the same thing, then it wouldn't be a fallacy to claim that we both must drive the same car).

Comment: I neither follow nor agree with your reasoning concerning the example; but that's a different topic. :) Fine. Take this example: *I have ears. Dogs have ears. Therefore, I am a dog.* That's a fallacy. But what is the name of the fallacy?

Comment: @gnasher729: When I say "I have ears. Dogs have ears. Therefore, I am a dog", then all of the premises in there are my own and thus when I make the argument, I assume their truth.
However, car owner A might postulate "I drive a car. The car I drive is the only one in existence." and from that and the fact that B's description of her car does not fit his car, he can conclude that B does not in fact drive a car (i.e. his car). You are acting like Muslims and Christians have a reason to assume the other person's premises are also true. There is no reason to do so in fact and guest is correct.